# Reading lines in a file

Tags: python-3.x, text-files

I want to make a function that reads lines from a text at certain points only. The file that I am going to read, for example, is named "text.txt".

Assume text.txt has the following 5 lines

```
X This is 1st line
X This is 2nd line
This is 3rd line
This is 4th line
This is 5th line
```

I want the function to print all the lines that does NOT start with an X. 
So far this is my attempt, but for some reason it does not print anything.

```
infile = open("text.txt", "r")

line = infile.readline()

while line != '':
    if 'X' not in line:
        line = infile.readline()
        print(line)
```

However, it works if text.txt is arranged as follows:

```
This is 1st line
This is 2nd line
This is 3rd line
X This is 4th line
X This is 5th line
```

Comment: Hint: try using `for line in infile:` instead of manually calling `readline` at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is faulty:

1. read a line
2. if it doesn't have an X, read ANOTHER line.
3. print that other line

Try:

```
if 'X' not in line:
   print(line)
line = infile.readline()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a `for`-loop to go through the entire file:

```
for line in open('test.txt'):
    if line[0] != 'X':
        if line[-1] == "\n":
            print(line[:-1])
        else:
            print(line)
```

Your basic problem is that if 'X' **is** in the line, you forget to update the line, so it keeps checking and checking and checking. (In other words, I think your code has an infinite loop.)